# Android Room DB migration with condition

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I migrated table in Room DB with mistake:

```
val MIGRATION_6_7 = object : Migration(6, 7) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE RideEntity ADD COLUMN state INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL")
        }
    }
```

Some user received the new column with 0 value. What I should have done is:

```
 val MIGRATION_6_7 = object : Migration(6, 7) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE RideEntity ADD COLUMN state INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL")
        }
    }
```

I need to do one more migration, for user that have 0 in that column need to change to 1. I am adding this migration:

```
   val MIGRATION_7_8 = object : Migration(7, 8) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("UPDATE TABLE RideEntity SET state 1 where state 0")
        }
    }
```

But I get " *or OR expected, got 'TABLE'*" how to achieve this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for the update statement is incorrect, it should be:

```
UPDATE RideEntity SET state = 1 where state = 0
```

You shouldn't have the `TABLE` keyword and you need to use the `=` operator for your update and condition.

You can take a look [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-update/) for some more information.